# visual c# enrollment system error invalid input

Tags: c#, system

we're ask to make an enrollment program using visual c#, i came up with the code but i think there's something wrong whenever i input number of units it always prompt  "invalid input" even though i input above 9 units because our professor said the units must not be less than 9. heres the code that i made

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MachineProblem2
{
public partial class frmEnrollment : Form
{
    public frmEnrollment()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rdbInstallment.Checked = true;
        rdbRegular.Checked = true;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCompute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int units = Convert.ToInt32(txtUnits.Text);
        int tuitionfee = 1250;
        double miscfee = .15;
        int labfee = 750;
        //double scholar = 0;
        //double fullpayment = 0;
        //double installment = .005;
        int totalTuition = 0;
        double totalMiscFee = 0;
        int totalLabFee = 0;
        int totalDiscount = 0;
        int computeModePayment = 0;
        int computeScholarDiscount = 0;
        int scholarDiscount = 80;
        int fullpaymentDiscount = 5;
        double modeOfPayment = 0;
        double status = 0;
        double convertedDiscount = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double installment = 0;

        if (txtUnits.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input a number", "Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }


        if (units < 9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Input!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtUnits.Clear();
            txtUnits.Focus();


        }
        else
            totalLabFee = units * labfee;
        txtLabFee.Text = totalLabFee.ToString("C");


        totalTuition = units * tuitionfee;
        txtTuitionFee.Text = totalTuition.ToString("C");

        totalMiscFee = totalTuition * miscfee;
        txtMiscFee.Text = totalMiscFee.ToString("C");

        totalLabFee = units * labfee;
        txtLabFee.Text = totalLabFee.ToString("C");

        if (rdbFull.Checked)
        {
            computeModePayment = fullpaymentDiscount;
        }
        else
            computeModePayment = 0;

        if (rdbScholar.Checked)
        {
            computeScholarDiscount = scholarDiscount;
        }
        else
            computeScholarDiscount = 0;

        totalDiscount = computeModePayment + computeScholarDiscount;
        txtDiscount.Text = totalDiscount.ToString();

        if (rdbFull.Checked)
        {
            modeOfPayment = totalTuition * 0.05;
        }
        else
            modeOfPayment = 0;

        if (rdbScholar.Checked)
        {
            status = totalTuition * .8;
        }
        else
            status = 0;

        convertedDiscount = modeOfPayment + status;
      //  txtConvertedDiscount.Text = convertedDiscount.ToString("C");

        if (rdbInstallment.Checked)
        {
            installment = totalTuition * .005;
            total = (totalTuition + totalLabFee + totalMiscFee - convertedDiscount) + installment;
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("C");
        }
        else
            total = totalTuition + totalLabFee + totalMiscFee - convertedDiscount;
        txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("C");

    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtUnits.Clear();
        txtTuitionFee.Clear();
        txtMiscFee.Clear();
        txtLabFee.Clear();
        txtDiscount.Clear();
        txtTotal.Clear();
       // txtConvertedDiscount.Clear();
        txtUnits.Focus();

        rdbFull.Checked = false;
        rdbInstallment.Checked = false;
        rdbRegular.Checked = false;
        rdbScholar.Checked = false;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Application",
           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
        }
        Close();
    }

}
}
```

here is the instruction of our professor, hope you can help me

*units must not be less than 9
* tuition fee is computed as 1250 per unit
*misc fee is computed as 1250 per unit
*lab fee is computed as 750 per unit
* 80% discount for scholar
*5% discount for full payment
*0.5 % charge for installment

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int units = Convert.ToInt32(txtUnits.Text).Trim();
```